# WhatsApp Business Platform API App is not creating

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm tring to create WhatsApp Business Platform API. it return erorr "onboard Please retry in some time or reach support to get issue fixed."  I tryed again and again but not solved

I'm creating WhatsApp Business Platform API but it return erorr Onboarding Failure
Please retry in some time or reach support to get issue fixed.and not creating App.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.